# Express-session not persistent

Tags: angularjs, express, express-session

im currently trying to save data in express sessions.

Im using the following packages:

```
"connect-mongo": "^0.8.2"
"express": "~4.0.0"
"express-session": "^1.11.3"
"mongoose": "~3.6.13"
```

I'm implementing the sessions this way:

```
// Loading packages
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

// Connect to MongoDB
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var options = { server: { socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1, connectTimeoutMS: 30000 } }, 
                replset: { socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1, connectTimeoutMS : 30000 } } };
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE, options);


var router = express.Router();

// Session storage
router.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection}),
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 60*60*24*7*1000
    }
}));

// Routes
router.route('/user/me')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.session);
    });

router.route('/auth/login')
    .post(function(req, res) {
        req.session.userId = req.params.id;
    });

app.use('/api', router);


var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

Now i have the following problem:
When i try posting to /api/auth/login using a software called "Postman REST Client" (Chrome extension) it works, and the user id will be logged when getting /api/user/me.

But if i try posting to /api/auth/login in an angular.js app, it does not save the session values. I always get a clean session object without the userId.

Also there are no cookies saved.

Could you please help me?

Greetings: Max